# When I'm testing with testing codes, with clean architecture, One of my test is returning NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, clean-architecture

I'm Testing app with clean architecture, koin, mockito. but it shows nullpointer exception. I searched a lot but couldn't get solution.. Please help me...
here is my codes. I'm making ToDo app with clean architecture.

```
internal class ListViewModelTest:ViewModelTest() {

  private val viewModel: ListViewModel by inject ()

  private val insertToDoListUseCase: InsertToDoListUseCase by inject()
  private val getToDoItemUseCase: GetToDoItemUseCase by inject()

  private val mockList= (0 until 10).map {
    ToDoEntity(
          id = it.toLong(),
          title = "title $it",
          description = "description $it",
          hasCompleted = false)
  }


    @Before
    fun init(){
        initData()
    }
    private fun initData() = runBlockingTest {
        insertToDoListUseCase(mockList)
    }
    @Test
    fun `test viewModel fetch`():Unit = runBlockingTest {
        val testObservable = viewModel.todoListLiveData.test()
        viewModel.fetchData()
        testObservable.assertValueSequence(
            listOf(
                mockList
            )
        )

    }
    
    @Test
    fun `test item Update`(): Unit = runBlockingTest {
        val todo = ToDoEntity(
            id = 1,
            title = "title 1",
            description = "description 1",
            hasCompleted = true
        )
        viewModel.updateEntity(todo)
        assert(getToDoItemUseCase(todo.id)?.hasCompleted ?: false == todo.hasCompleted)
    }

}
```

this is my ViewModelTest

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
internal abstract class ViewModelTest: KoinTest {
    @get:Rule
    val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var context: Application

    private val dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        startKoin{
            androidContext(context)
            modules(appTestModule)
        }
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown(){
        stopKoin()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    protected fun <T> LiveData<T>.test(): LiveDataTestObserver<T>{
        val testObserver = LiveDataTestObserver<T>()
        observeForever(testObserver)
        return testObserver
    }
}
```

first test is having nullpointerexception.. whats the problem?

Comment: the problem is that you haven't posted exception stacktrace, so nobody knows where to look for cause

Answer (score 0):

I think

> private lateinit var context: Application

make problem so set initial value of context